# Best way to implement an array of buffers in C (linear array vs. scattered array)

Tags: c, arrays

I have created an array of buffers as

```
int myBuffers[NUM_BUF][SIZE_BUF];
```

I need to be able to do two things. 1) Pass an individual buffer to a function by reference 2) pass an array of pointers to each buffer to a function

Regarding #1, does the following syntax correctly resolve to a pointer to buffer i? Or is this undefined or something else?

```
ProcessBuffer(myBuffers[i]);
```

Regarding #2, I have found that the following does not resolve to a pointer to a pointer like I originally expected:

```
ProcessAllBuffers(myBuffers);
```

What would be the best way to handle this? Should I create an array of pointers and iteratively assign each element to point to myBuffers[i]? Or is there a cleaner way to handle this?

Comment: The decision heavily depend on how you are going to use the seperate buffers. And also if their size needs to stay the same or if the need to change the size of a single buffer might occur.

Comment: Although answers to this question might surely be "option based", those options also surely follow needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need an array of pointers to `int`, you will need to create one. Although a C array decays to a pointer when used in an expression (with notable exceptions such as `sizeof`), this process is not associative - while an array of arrays of `int` will decay into a pointer to an array of `int`, it will never decay into an array of pointers to `int`.

Answer (score 1):

1 - myBuffers[i] is a pointer to the first element in buffer i.

2 - myBuffers I believe is a pointer to the first element of the first buffer (buffer 0).

> Should I create an array of pointers and iteratively assign each element to point to myBuffers[i]?

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key point is the type of your function parameter.

For `ProcessBuffer`, its parameter type should be `(int * a)`, a pointer to int. After you pass `myBuffers[i]` to `a`, `a[j]` will point to the jth element in buffer i. Where `a[j]` equals `*(a +j)`.

For `ProcessAllBuffers`, its parameter type should be `(int （*aa)[])`, a pointer to an int array . After pass the name of you 2D array `myBuffers` to `aa` you could use `*(*aa + i)` to go through each element in the 2D array.

Comment: If used as by the OP `ProcessAllBuffers()` shall be declared as `ProcessAllBuffers(int (*pa)[SIZE_BUF]`.

Comment: Thanks alk! My mistake, using `(int **aa)` will causes **Segmentation fault**. 2D array's name means a pointer to 1D array. I corrected that in my answer.